# Will local variables still be in scope on an Ajax call back?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to call an internal function once an ajax call back function is activated.  Because there is a delay I want to know if my local variables will still be correct when it is called, particularly this.response_element as it is used by the call back function.

The callback function is initiated when ajax `status == 200`

```
var ControlSignIn = function( ) 
{
    this.form_element = document.getElementById( 'signin' ),
    this.response_element = document.getElementById( 'signin_response' ),
    this.text_object = new Text( this.form_element ), 
    this.message_object = new Message( this.response_element );
};

ControlSignIn.interface = function()
{
    new ControlSignIn().invoke();
};

ControlSignIn.prototype.invoke = function( ) 
{
    if( CONSTANT.VALIDATE_ON === 1 )
    {
        if( !this.text_object.checkEmpty() ) 
        {
            this.message_object.display( 'empty' );
            return false;
        }
        if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'email' ) ) 
        {
            this.message_object.display( 'email' );
            return false;
        }
        if( !this.text_object.checkPattern( 'pass' ) ) 
        {
            this.message_object.display( 'pass' );
            return false;
        }
    }

/* new internal call_back */    

        AjaxNew.use( ajaxSerialize( this.form_element ) + '&ajax_type=ControlSignIn', ControlSignIn.invoke.callBack );

    function callBack( server_response_text )
    {
        ajaxType( server_response_text, this.response_element, 'respond' ); 
    }

/*  Removed
    Ajax.repeatUse( ajaxSerialize( this.form_element ) + '&ajax_type=ControlSignIn', ajaxTypeRespond, this.response_element );
*/

};
```

**Solution:**

```
AjaxNew.use( ajaxSerialize( this.form_element ) + '&ajax_type=ControlSignIn', ControlSignIn.invoke.callBack );

var response_element = this.response_element;
function callBack( server_response_text )
{
    ajaxType( server_response_text, response_element, 'respond' ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. Eventhough the property may be intact, `this` won't point to the object.

Copy the value to a local variable, and use a function literal, then the local variable will be catched in the closure for the function and kept intact and accessible:

```
var element = this.response_element;
AjaxNew.use(
  ajaxSerialize(this.form_element) + '&ajax_type=ControlSignIn',
  function(server_response_text) {
    ajaxType(server_response_text, element, 'respond'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no.  Yes, local variables will still be around, but the `this` reference is always reset on **every** function call. Thus the callback will have its own `this` value.

The solution is to leverage the "yes" part of the answer and save your `this` reference in another variable. Then you use that variable (instead of `this`) in the callback.

Now, that said, the structure of your code confuses me a little and I can't exactly tell how your "callback" is supposed to work; that is, it references `this` but I don't see how it expects it to be set.

Comment: You're probably thinking about using `someFunction.call( what_this_should_be, arg, arg ...)`